# Does Core Audio / OpenAL resample audio files?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, openal

I've noticed that if my audio files are in caf 11250Hz mono they perform worse than 44.1Khz mono. Tracing it with profiler I can see that for the low sample rate files one of the longest traces ends with LinearConverterInt32. This isn't present in the 44.1KHz trace.

I want to use the lower sample rate files to keep file size (and hopefully memory size) down.

I've noticed in my log file that I get this
AudioStreamBasicDescription:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved

So I am guessing that this is the format it is converting to, but I have no idea how to tell it to use 1 ch, 11250 Hz 16 bit.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Core Audio can resample, and probably does, as an app does not have control over the actual hardware sample rate.  The OS does, probably depending on the device type, the OS version, the audio session type of your app and any other apps that have previously run or are currently in the background (and/or the phase-of-the-moon, etc.)

Comment: In the end I used higher sample rate stereo files, the performance is better though memory performance and app size is worse.

Comment: You can set the audio samplerate using Core audio

Comment: An audio unit's software interface sample rate, yes.  But not the actual hardware DAC sample rate on at least some older device models.  Thus the potential need for the OS or device driver to do some resampling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conserve memory, you should use 44.1 kHz audio compressed with IMA 4:1 in CAF file format. It does introduce some noise, though, so you should do some listening test to see if it's right for you.

Comment: Actually, my understanding is that all audio is uncompressed before used by an app, thus a compressed IMA4 will still use up the same memory as an uncompressed PCM, but it will make the overall download size of the app smaller.

Comment: @johnbakers How much memory it uses in ram is meaningless, because it's buffered.